# Print Button inside DataTemplate? How to write code

Tags: wpf, button, resources, resourcedictionary

I have a ContentControl element whose ContentTemplate is determined at run time from the Resource Dictionary. In the datatemplate I have a visual (Convas) and what I want is to also have a button in datatemplate which when clicked should print the visual element(canvas). 
As I said that the DateTemplate is inside the Resource Dictionary so How can I write a Code on Click Event of that button and where it should be?

Any response would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can use the Button.Click attached event.  Just add it to the ContentControl.

```
<ContentControl 
    Button.Click="Button_Click" 
    ContentTemplate="<template with a button>"   
/>
```

and the handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

If you have multiple buttons in your template, you can use `e.Source` to figure it out.  And I think you can use `MouseButtonEventArgs` instead.